Debian Bookworm Inrelease public keys error preventing Docker from building Auto-GPT on Windows 7
I am a newb.
I am trying to build AutoGPT on Windows 7.  As you may imagine I have run into some difficulties, but I overcame most of them by changing .yml files for docker compose to have a different version header and then removing the code that was preventing compose from starting the build.
Now that the build has started I am getting the following errors.  I know that it is possible from reading other posts to overcome this by upgrading Docker to version 20, however it is not possible for me to practically do that because I cannot use Docker Desktop on Windows 7, I can only use Docker toolbox, and I even downloaded an older version (18.0) in order to get it to match with the Compose version that will function on my system.  This resolved the issue I was previously having that compose would not run at all.  Unless I am mistaken on my ability to update these systems, what is a workaround I can use to overcome the public keys issue with apt-get on the debian bookworm in-release portion of the build?
OS:  Windows 7
Using Visual Code Editor
Using Docker Toolbox (Docker Quickstart Terminal)
Here is the error message and docker version infos.
Engine:
Version:          19.03.12
API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.13.10
Git commit:       48a66213fe
Built:            Mon Jun 22 15:49:35 2020
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          v1.2.13
GitCommit:
7ad184331fa3e55e52b890ea95e65ba581ae3429
runc:
Version:          1.0.0-rc10
GitCommit:
dc9208a3303feef5b3839f4323d9beb36df0a9dd
docker-init:
Version:          0.18.0
GitCommit:        fec3683
Err:1 /debian bookworm InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
Err:2 debian bookworm-updates InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Err:3 /debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
Reading package lists...
W: GPG error: /debian bookworm InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
E: The repository /debian bookworm InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: /debian bookworm-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
E: The repository '/debian bookworm-updates InRelease' is not signed.
W: GPG error: //debian-security bookworm-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
E: The repository /debian-security bookworm-security InRelease' is not signed.
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
ERROR: Service 'migrate' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y build-essential curl ffmpeg wget libcurl4-gnutls-dev libexpat1-dev libpq5 gettext libz-dev libssl-dev postgresql-client git     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*' returned a non-zero code: 100
**** NOTE **** I removed the information from the above error that was "http://debian.org/bookworm" etc. from all the above references because stackoverflow thought I was posting links and wouldn't allow me to post that quantity without a higher reputation.
Thanks in advance for any advice!
